# Importar .tif, Extraer y Unir desde directorio en R

Tags: r

Tengo que importar desde un directorio muchos archivos .tif, una vez cargados tengo que transformarlos (o al menos es la única manera que se me ocurre) en dataframes, y luego unirlos en único dataframe, y todo esto de manera masiva.

Ahora mismo tengo esto, importo de manera masiva los .tif, pero desde ese momento se me separan, y al no estar en una lista ya no se como convertirlos en dataframe con un bucle, tengo que hacerlo convirtiéndolos de manera manual, y la consiguiente creación de la lista para poder unirlos.

```
setwd("C:/Users/jemor/Documents/R/TFG")
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
rlist=list.files(getwd(), pattern="tif$", full.names=FALSE)
for(i in rlist) {assign(unlist(strsplit(i, "[.]"))[1], raster(i))}
df1 <- as.data.frame(rasterToPoints(Imagen_1_20171016))
df2 <- as.data.frame(rasterToPoints(Imagen_2_20171016))
df3 <- as.data.frame(rasterToPoints(Imagen_3_20171026))
df4 <- as.data.frame(rasterToPoints(Imagen_4_20171026))

dff <- Reduce(merge, list(df1, df2, df3, df4))
```

La solución que sería meter un bucle dentro del primero que transforme todo lo anterior?
Agradecería mucho algo de luz.

Comment: Bienvenido  a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por que no, directamente creas una lista (variable) con los `data.frames`, algo así:

```
sp_objects = list()
for(i in rlist) {
  sp_objects[[i]] <- as.data.frame(rasterToPoints(raster(i)))
}

dff <- Reduce(merge, sp_objects)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @Patricio Moracho, me soluciona perfectamente la pregunta pero justo hace 30 min acababa de solucionarlo de esta otra manera:

`tiflist <- list.files(pattern='tif$', full.names=TRUE)

rasterlist <- lapply(tiflist, raster)

rasterstack <- stack(rasterlist)

df <- as.data.frame(rasterToPoints(rasterstack))`

Realmente ahora no se cual dejar, con lapply aplico la raster a la primera lista y después los uno con stack, el resto es lo mismo.